# How can I make a rectangle change between 2 colors periodically?

Tags: java

I’ve been trying to make a program that will display a visual metronome that will flash in sync with a MIDI file by sensing a “click” track that I have added using a MIDI editor.

I only have a basic knowledge of Java programming but have been hacking my way through this project. In particular, I’m having problems with the graphical portion. As part of my testing and troubleshooting, I have added a println in a conditional statement that is true when the “click” starts, and this part seems to work well.

The clicks occur about 2 times per second, and each click lasts for about 1/10 of a second. I would like a rectangle shape that is red during the time the click is present, and gray when the click is not present. The attached code actually sorta works (a total hack job I’m sure) , but is one beat off (there is 72 clicks on the MIDI file I’ve been working with, but the JFrame only flashes 71 times).

I suspect the proper way would be to draw a rectangle and somehow change, or update, the fill color in the conditional statements. I’ve spent much time researching this and trying different approaches, but I really have no idea what would be the proper way to proceed.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance and maybe some code snippets.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.midi.InvalidMidiDataException;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiMessage;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.midi.Receiver;
import javax.sound.midi.Sequence;
import javax.sound.midi.Sequencer;
import javax.sound.midi.ShortMessage;
import javax.sound.midi.Transmitter;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Midi6 extends JPanel implements Receiver 
{
    private static final int NOTE_ON = 144;
    private static final int NOTE_OFF = 128;
    int count = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
    String str = new String();

    public Midi6() throws MidiUnavailableException, InvalidMidiDataException, IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        Sequence sequence = MidiSystem.getSequence(new File("miditest2.mid"));
        sequencer.open();
        sequencer.setSequence(sequence);
        Transmitter transmitter = sequencer.getTransmitter();
        transmitter.setReceiver(this);
        sequencer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidMidiDataException, IOException, MidiUnavailableException, InterruptedException
    {
        Midi6 midi6 = new Midi6();  
        JFrame frame1=new JFrame(); 
        frame1.add(midi6);  
        frame1.setSize(600,100);
        frame1.getContentPane().setBackground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        frame1.setVisible(true);
    }

    synchronized public void send(MidiMessage message, long timeStamp) 
    {       
        if(message instanceof ShortMessage) 
        {
            ShortMessage sm = (ShortMessage) message;
            int channel = sm.getChannel();

            if (sm.getCommand() == NOTE_ON)            
            {               
                if (channel == 0)
                {  
                    setBackground(Color.RED);
                    count ++;
                    System.out.println(count); 
                }
            } 
            else if (sm.getCommand() == NOTE_OFF) 
            {               
                if (channel == 0)
                {
                    setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                }
            }
            else 
            {

            }
        }
    }     
    @Override
    public void close() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }    
}
```

Comment: I might be able to help but it would be useful to have the `midi` file.

Comment: I would be glad to share it with you, however, I don't see a way to attach the file......

Comment: The only way I know to do that is to use one of the public dropbox types of services and include a link.  If you do that I am willing to take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the offer WJS. I found a bit of a workaround to avoid the missing beat (added a blank measure at the beginning of the MIDI file). It seems the setBackground method using the JFrame object may be the best way to go for changing the color. I'm not sure if there are any other options, but this seems to be working pretty good, and it is fairly straight forward. Using the fillRectangle seems to be very convoluted and not easily implemented in my code. Thanks again. Cheers!

Comment: In the future, I will try to keep my questions shorter and more concise.

Comment: Turns out my cpu was running 100% at times and that was the real source of the error, svchost.exe was the culprit, and once i ended the process, the code works really well.  Guess thats what I get for blowing off windows updates for about 5 years.